# Compare two version numbers with version in ansible

Tags: ansible, version

I am writing a playbook that only should run when a new package version of a software is available.
Both version numbers are custom facts I set with "set_fact"

Ansible let's you compare version numbers, so I tried it like this:

```
- name: compare versions
  debug:
    msg: "The version {{ new_version }} is newer than the old version {{ old_version }}"
  when: "{{ new_version is version('{{ old_version }}', '>', strict=True }}"
```

Ansible throws an error that the version number is invalid. When I set "old_version" to a fixed version number it works as expected.
Is it possible to compare two facts with "version"?
I already tried different approaches with double-quotes etc which leads to syntax errors in ansible.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be use of Jinja delimiters `{{` in a conditional. In a `when:` condition you don't need these delimiters to interpolate.

Example below works:

```yaml
vars:
  new_version: 14
  old_version: 12

tasks:
- debug:
    msg:  'The version {{ new_version }} is newer than the old version {{ old_version }}'
  when: "new_version is version(old_version, '>')"
```

Comment: Ah, I see :) This works also in my playbook, nice, thank you alot!

Comment: work for me too, thanks